# How to make exception handler using events

Tags: c#, events, exception

I have dll Scripting. In that dll I have class named Scripter. In Scripter class i call some methods which loads data from MySQL database (LoadTables()). In that functions which loads data from MySQL database exception could happen. I want to be able, later in my app where I use Scripting.dll, to do something like this:

```
 Scrpter sc = new Scripter();
 sc.OnError += ErrorOccured;
```

And want to have function ErrorOcured in my app which will be like:

```
private void ErrorOccured(Exception exception)
{...}
```

What I need to have in Scripter class, and how should I pass exception in catch block in LoadTables so I could later use ErrorOcured() to see what happend wrong?

Comment: You can just `throw` the exceptions in the `Scripter` class and catch them in a `try/catch` in your application,no need to create an event.

Comment: It's actually quite easy to do, but I would advise against it. Exceptions and events are quite different things and exceptions should not be handled using events, but instead using try...catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to modify your Scripter class like this

```
class Scripter
{
    public event EventHandler<Exception> ErrorOcurred;

    protected virtual void OnErrorOcurred(Exception e)=>ErrorOcurred?.Invoke(this, e);

    public void ThrowsException()
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("Throws exception");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnErrorOcurred(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can subscribe to ErrorOcurred and receive notifications about exceptions. You must call OnErrorOcurred in every place you catch an exception

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks it was helpful

Answer (score 2):

As Picoh and Zoltan commented on your question, you can easily wrap method calls to `Scripter` methods in `try/catch` block. But, if you want to use event (with custom args), you can do something like this:

```
//your class
public class Scripter
{
    public Scripter()
    {
    }

    //public event with custom event args
    public EventHandler<ScripterErrorEventArgs> OnError;

    //just for test
    public void RaiseError()
    {
        //error which is caught here
        Exception ex = new Exception("something happened");
        OnError?.Invoke(this, new ScripterErrorEventArgs(ex));
    }
}

//class for custom event args. add your own other properties as needed
public class ScripterErrorEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ScripterErrorEventArgs()
    {

    }

    public ScripterErrorEventArgs(Exception ex)
    {
        this.Exception = ex;
    }

    public Exception Exception { get; set; }
}


//usage
public void someMethod()
{
    Scripter s = new Scripter();
    s.OnError +=  new EventHandler<ScripterErrorEventArgs>(LogError)
    s.RaiseError();
}

private void LogError(object sender, ScripterErrorEventArgs e)
{
    //your code here
}
```